# How can I update a Firebase Realtime Database when I modify a Svelte store?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, svelte, sveltekit

I've seen lots of examples of updating a svelte store from a Firestore (note I'm using a realtime database instead) but I'd like my database to update based off a change to the svelte store. At the moment I have lots of functions that look like this:

```
// Saves a list of the selected profiles to the scenario data
export const saveProfileData = (dataStore, sliderStore, popupIDs, scenarioID) => {
  const sliderData = get(sliderStore);
  const data = get(dataStore);

  const scenarioData = data[scenarioID]
  scenarioData.profileSave = {}
  for (const popupID of popupIDs){
    if (sliderData[popupID].hasOwnProperty("slider3")){
      scenarioData.profileSave[popupID] = sliderData[popupID].slider3.profile
    }
  } 
  dataStore.set(data)
}
```

Where the `dataStore` is my Svelte writable store which I'd like to sync with the database (as calculations are done in a cloud function from the database). Note I have a seperate store `sliderStore` which I am not syncing.

I'm aware of things like `sveltefire` which sync it from server -> UI, so should I update my database in the functions instead of my store and then sync it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your database based on changes in a Svelte store, you'll need to have a mechanism to detect changes in the store and trigger the corresponding database update. Since you are using Firestore's realtime database, you might not have built-in capabilities like Firestore's onSnapshot for real-time updates.

Here's a general approach you can take:

Use Svelte's store subscription: Svelte stores have a subscribe method that allows you to subscribe to changes. You can use this to detect changes in your store.

Trigger a database update: When the store changes, you can trigger a function to update your Firebase Realtime Database.

Here is a simplified example:

```
// dataStore.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const createDataStore = () => {
  const { subscribe, set } = writable({});

  return {
    subscribe,
    updateData: (newData) => set(newData),
  };
};

export const dataStore = createDataStore();
```

In your component, you can use subscribe to listen for changes in the store:

```
// Your Svelte component
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { dataStore } from './dataStore';

onMount(() => {
  const unsubscribe = dataStore.subscribe((newData) => {
    // Do something with the updated data, e.g., update the database
    updateDatabase(newData);
  });

  // Cleanup the subscription when the component is destroyed
  return () => unsubscribe();
});
```

Now, when you call dataStore.updateData(newData), the database update function (updateDatabase) will be triggered.

Keep in mind that the updateDatabase function should be implemented based on your specific database setup. You might need to use a library like Firebase to interact with your Realtime Database.

Also, be cautious about the frequency of updates to the database to avoid unnecessary calls. You might consider debouncing the updates if your store changes frequently.

Comment: This is great thanks, I've made my stores subscribable. My writable store is a fairly big json, and I only need to really update specific portions of the database. Is there any way to do this in a more targeted way, or is there no point as this would make the sync more likely to go wrong?

Comment: Target specific portions when updating the database from a Svelte writable store. Extract only relevant data changes and update the corresponding database section. Minimize data transfer and reduce the risk of synchronization issues.